# How to resize YUV image in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

How can I resize a YUV image in CUDA? I tried converting libyuv’s scaling code to CUDA, but the performance is very bad.

```
void ScalePlaneSimple(int src_width, int src_height,
int dst_width, int dst_height,
int src_stride, int dst_stride,
const Npp8u* src_ptr, Npp8u* dst_ptr) {
    int i;
    // Initial source x/y coordinate and step values as 16.16 fixed point.
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int dx = 0;
    int dy = 0;

ScaleSlope(src_width, src_height, dst_width, dst_height, kFilterNone,
    &x, &y, &dx, &dy);
src_width = Abs(src_width);
    if (src_width * 2 == dst_width && x < 0x8000) {
        for (i = 0; i < dst_height; ++i) {
            ScaleColsUp2_C(dst_ptr, src_ptr + (y >> 16) * src_stride, dst_width, x, dx);
            dst_ptr += dst_stride;
            y += dy;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < dst_height; ++i) {
        ScaleCols_C<<<1,1>>>(dst_ptr, src_ptr + (y >> 16) * src_stride, dst_width, x, dx);
            dst_ptr += dst_stride;
            y += dy;
        }
    }
}
__global__ void ScaleCols_C(Npp8u* dst_ptr, const Npp8u* src_ptr,
    int dst_width, int x, int dx) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < dst_width - 1; j += 2) {
        dst_ptr[0] = src_ptr[x >> 16];
        x += dx;
        dst_ptr[1] = src_ptr[x >> 16];
        x += dx;
        dst_ptr += 2;
}
    if (dst_width & 1) {
        dst_ptr[0] = src_ptr[x >> 16];
    }
}
```

Maybe I should use parallel computing? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I see lots of loops here, which isn't like a typical cuda implementation. And since you are using NPP data structure, why not use npp functions to do this? Though npp doesn't provide a yuv resize one, have to convert to rgb to resize, and nppiResizeSqrPixel functions resulting poor image when shrinking.

Comment: You are running 1 thread. What point is there is complaining about performance when you are deliberately leaving about 99.99% of the computational capacity of your GPU idle?

Comment: How is this an assembly question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cuda, take a look at the NVidia performance primitives. There are image resizing functions.  (It's a copy of the interface for the Intel performance primitives, if you don't want to use the gpu)

Comment: thanks,I have found sample code in nvidia_video_sdk( CNvEncoderLowLatency::ScaleNV12Image),I hope I can find mixing NV12Image too